# GNU Profiler Empty Flat Profile

Tags: profiling, virtualbox, gprof

I am trying to learn profiling with GNU gprof, and I just tried to take the same results as in this tutorial by using exactly the same code and applying the same steps there: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gnuprof.html

However, when I try to reach flat profile by `gprof example1 gmon.out -p`, what I see nothing. It says

> Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds. no time accumulated

and I am seeing an empty flat profile. And when I try to obtain call graph, I receive

> gprof: gmon.out file is missing call-graph data

I am using Ubuntu on a VirtualBox VM. May using VirtualBox be the reason?

Comment: The first thing to learn about gprof is [*you can do better.*](http://archive.today/9r927)

Comment: Mike, do you think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof should be reopened (undeleted to closed state)? There are votes for it already.